# Class not found : helloworld.Main

Tags: haxe

I just began to learn Haxe, but I have encountered Compile error.

**Main.hx**

```
package helloworld;

import js.Lib;

class Main {

    static function main() {
        Lib.alert("Hello World");
    }

}
```

Please be careful about the target class is `helloworld.Main`.

**build.hxml**

```
-js bin/HelloWorld.js
-cp src
-main helloworld.Main
-debug
```

**Build process log**

```
Building HelloWorld_p140627
Running Pre-Build Command Line...
cmd: C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\haxe.exe X:\tmp\HelloWorld_p140627\build.hxml
Class not found : helloworld.Main
Build halted with errors.
Done(1)
```

[image]

Why? The class `helloworld.Main` is surely exist. I cannot even say "hello, world"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update now that I can see a screenshot of your project:**

You are trying to compile "helloworld.Main", that means a class called "Main" in the package "helloworld", so Haxe will be looking for a file called "helloworld/Main.hx" in your "src/" directory.

However you have "src/Main.hx", not "src/helloworld/Main.hx".  Create a subfolder called "helloworld", move "Main.hx" in there and you will be fine.  The package you use in Haxe must match the directory structure.

---

Make sure your package aligns with your folders, and your file name with your class name.  And all of these should be inside one of your "-cp" class path folders.

For your example above, the code looks fine, I would expect your layout to look like:

```
build.hxml                  <-- build file
src/helloworld/Main.hx      <-- classpath/package/class.Hx
bin/                        <-- output folder
bin/HelloWorld.js           <-- will be created once it compiles
```

And then you'd run `haxe build.hxml`.  If that doesn't work for you please post the exact file structure of your project (which folders and which directories), and the command you use to build it, and the output.

Hope that helps,

Comment: I confirmed the file layout of the project, but there is no curious point. I have added the layout above. Could you please find the reason of compile error?

Comment: Update my answer. The thing you're missing is that you are asking for "helloworld.Main", that is, "src/helloworld/Main.hx", and that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you very much Jason, I have understood. I success the compile.